# determine convergence or divergence of a series, finding sum of series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I am given the series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1+2^n}{3^n}$$

So I used ratio test for this one to see if this converges and I found out that it converges, however the answer key tells me there is a geometric sum for this and I don't know how to transform this geometrically because of the numerator making it complicated. Please help.

Comment: Break it into two geometric series: $\sum (1/3)^n$ and $\sum (2/3)^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1+2^n}{3^n}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\frac{2}{3})^n$$
see, these two geometric series

to find the sum

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n}=-(1+\frac{1}{3})+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n}=-(1+\frac{1}{3})+\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}}$$
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\frac{2}{3})^n=-(1+\frac{2}{3})+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{2}{3})^n=-(1+\frac{2}{3})+\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{3}}$$

Comment: I also did this only wasn't able to subtract the first two terms of each sequence. Thank you!

Comment: @marg_ocruz you are welcome